# HAProxy ACL to multiple backend ports not working

Tags: reverse-proxy, configuration, haproxy, access-control-list

I'm trying to set up haproxy to navigate between the multiple applications running on the same server.  If my understanding is correct, I should be able to use ACL rules in the frontend to switch between ports based on the path passed to it.  however, everytime I try, I get `503 Service Unavailable`.  I'm using version 1.5.18 of HAProxy, and have confirmed that the services I want are up and running on the correct ports.  My config file is:

```
global
  log 127.0.0.1   local0
  log 127.0.0.1   local1 notice
  #log loghost    local0 info
  maxconn 4096
  #debug
  #quiet
  user root
  group root

#/installs version
defaults
  log     global
  mode    http
  retries 3
  timeout client 50s
  timeout connect 5s
  timeout server 50s
  option tcplog
  balance  roundrobin

# Set up application listeners here.

listen admin
  bind 127.0.0.1:22002
  mode http
  stats enable
  stats show-node
  stats uri  /admin


frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:4000

  acl configuration-path path -i /configuration
  use_backend servers-configuration if config-path

  acl payment-path path -i /payment
  use_backend servers-paymentdate if payment-path

  acl employee-path path -i /employee
  use_backend servers-employeename if employee-path


backend servers-configuration
  server www.server1.com 12.12.12.12:3000 maxconn 100

backend servers-paymentdate
  server www.server1.com 12.12.12.12:3001 maxconn 100

backend servers-employeename
  server www.server1.com 12.12.12.12:3001 maxconn 100
```

So, for example, if I try:

```
12.12.12.12:3000/config/id
```

I'm able to get the results I expect. However, when I try

```
12.12.12.12:4000/configuration
#or
12.12.12.12:4000/configuration/config/to/service
```

It fails.  So far the only way I've been able to get results from one of the paths is to remove the acl rule for it and include a default backend:

```
frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:4000

  acl payment-path path -i /payment
  use_backend servers-paymentdate if payment-path

  acl employee-path path -i /employee
  use_backend servers-employeename if employee-path

  default_backend servers-configuration
```

Which let me use the path:

```
12.12.12.12:4000/config/id
```

This is obviously not going to work for all of them, though.  Can anyone tell me what I have wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  In order for the ACL to work, I need to put in the full path for the service:

```
frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:4000  

  acl payment_path path_beg -i /payment/list
  use_backend servers-paymentdate if payment-path

  acl employee-path path_beg -i /employee/list
  use_backend servers-employeename if employee-path
```

This is not ideal, so I'm looking through how regex works in these acl.

Edit:  Was able to figure this out.  I just had to set up a path_reg:

```
frontend http
  maxconn 2000
  bind 0.0.0.0:4000  

  acl payment_path path_beg -i /payment.*
  use_backend servers-paymentdate if payment-path

  acl employee-path path_beg -i /employee.*
  use_backend servers-employeename if employee-path
```

Comment: You solved not because you specified the full path, but I think, because you switched to used path_beg

Comment: I don't think so - I'm using path right now, and it still works as expected.

Comment: did you tried using /payment/ and /employee/ ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use `path_beg -i` then regex `.*` is not necessary. As `path_beg -i` already implies a url starting with certain string i.e /payment will match any url starting with /payment. Here `-i` indicates that matching is performed ignoring case. Below are the docs snippets extracted from HaProxy's official site found [here](https://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/configuration-1.5.html): (page is deprecated though, because HaProxy 1.5 is pretty old now)

```
ACL derivatives :
  path     : exact string match
  path_beg : prefix match
  path_dir : subdir match
  path_dom : domain match
  path_end : suffix match
  path_len : length match
  path_reg : regex match
  path_sub : substring match
```